# access django app through mobile browser

Tags: python, django, server

I've made a project to Django, everything is fine and I use the PC local IP that Ipconfig (I'm a windows user) shows me to run server (192.168.1.4:5000). I can access the project through other laptop connected to the same wireless but can't access it through my phone browser, I've disabled firewall and also no VPN is connected in my phone. I've no idea what's wrong.

Comment: If your sole purpose is to see how your website looks on mobile you can change the layout in your browser as well.

Comment: I tried in my office and everything went fine but I still have problem at my home, maybe the problem is from the modem configuration, any tip?